# take back is equal to give back?

Tags: word-usage, phrasal-verbs

I know "give sth back" means "to return something to the person who gave it to you", and "take sth back" means "to return something you have bought to a shop", according to "https://dictionary.cambridge.org". But I am wondering whether it is possible to use the latter one in lieu of the former one. I mean one can say:

> Make sure you take me the keys back when you've finished.

Comment: No, here we would use _bring_ if the borrower is being asked to return the keys to the place where the lender is.

Comment: We can distinguish take back **from** from take back **to**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Make sure you take me the keys back when you've finished.

No, that's not a proper usage of "take back". However if you lend something to someone and you want to take it back, it can be used like:

> I want to take back my book from Jason.

And a proper way for your sentence would be:

> Make sure to give the keys back to me when you've finished.